# Занесение данных в базу данных на PHP

Tags: база-данных, php

Скажите, пожалуйста, данные в базу данных будут занесены только тогда, когда будет закрыто соединение или нет?

Answer (score 2):

НЕТ!!! Когда делаете запросы.

Answer (score 2):

Открываете соединение

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass); 
mysql_select_db($db, $link);
```

Делаете запрос

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mybesttable (f1,f2) VALUES('f1val','f2val')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно нет. Пример из реальной жизни: "Можно ли набрать ведро воды из крана если он закрыт и не течёт?"

Answer (score 0):

Либо сразу после запросов INSERT либо после завершения транзакций в которых присутствуют INSERT'ы.

Answer (score 0):

Данные в БД будут занесены в случае успешного выполнения запроса (TRUE) [mysql_query()](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql-query). В случае ошибки вернется FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос. На него нельзя дать однозначный ответ, не зная всей специфики аппаратного и программного обеспечения.

Например, данные, вроде как записанные на диск, могут кэшироваться в буфере операционной системы. То есть соединение уже закрыто, СУБД отрапортовала, что данные записаны, а на самом деле на диске их ещё нет - они в буфере. И при внезапном отключении питания они пропадут.

Конечно, такое поведение не у всех накопителей. Однако, для серверов дожно применяться сертифицированное оборудование, производитель которого гарантирует наличие возможности принудительного сброса буферов на диск.